# Passing props on a button? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this button going this this link and I need to pass props to the link component, specifically currentUserProfile and selectedUserProfile, how can I do this?

```
<Button
    content='Private messages'
    color='green'
    as={Link}
    to={`/messages/${currentUserProfile.id}/${selectedUserProfile.id}`}
/>
```

this is the route

```
<Route
    path='/messages/:currentUser/:currentProfile'
    component={PrivateMessages}
/>
```

Comment: What is the current behavior with the code you have? What's the expected behavior? Is this using styled-components?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
function Button(props) {
  const { content, color } = props
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

then the place where you calling you component you can do something like

```
function SomeComponent(){
 return(
  <Button content='Private messages' color='green'>
     <Link to=`/messages/${currentUserProfile.id}/${selectedUserProfile.id}`>Link Here </Link>
  <Button>)
}
```